# javascript class constructor initialize array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

so i wonder how to initialize an array in a class constructor:

```
class test{

    constructor(){
        //here i want to initialize a new array called "array" from the class "class2"
        let array = [new class2()]; //is this the way to do it?
    }

    add(x){
        for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] == null){
                array[i] = x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to make give that array some values of another class, like class2 has another constructor with some values (lets say name and age)

Comment: you can extend your class with class2 and use `super()` function to delegate values from class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable your initialize will be bound to the constructor context. Which mean you could use them again in the constructor but it won't be accessible outside of that function.

Since you are using ES6 classes, you could add a class variable that would contains this array. You would need to access it using `this` but it would work fine.

```
class test{


    constructor(){
        // this variable will be accessible from everywhere in the class
        this.array = [new class2()]; 
    }

    add(x){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++){
            if(this.array[i] == null){
                this.array[i] = x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```